# Jump to Definition goes to derived data folder for static library's header files instead of the static library project

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I have an iOS app that has a static library as a dependency. The static library is setup per Apple's recommendations https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/iOSStaticLibraries.pdf

Sometimes when I use "Jump to Definition" on a symbol from the static library I end up in the header file that has been copied to the derived data folder of the app instead of the header file inside the static library project. Other times things work perfectly.

When "Jump to Definition" fails more often than not I delete the derived data folder for the project through the Organizer window and this seems to fix the problem temporarily.

Does anyone know if there is a way to tell Xcode to exclude the derived data folder from "Jump to Definition"?

Answer (score 1):

select 'Build Phases' -> 'Target Dependencies';
add your static library .

Comment: I am already doing this with all of my projects. The problem still occurs.